Find matching parenthesis
I have the following input file:
VARA {APPLE}
VARB {
          ORANGE
          BANANA
     }
VARC {
          KIWI{0}
          KIWI{1}
          BERRY
     }
VARD {CHERRY{0} MELON}

I would like to get the following output when processing this file:
VARA APPLE
VARB ORANGE BANANA
VARC KIWI{0} KIWI{1} BERRY
VARD CHERRY{0} MELON

Before writing a script, I wonder if there is any elegant way to solve this by just using grep. Otherwise, I would probably read the input file character by character, count the number of parenthesis and thereby find the matching parenthesis and print the above text.

This question is similar to: Using RegEx to balance match parenthesis. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I love grep for its power and flexibility, but so far as I know it cannot be used in any language to modify strings.
Provided the regex engine supports lookarounds I believe you could replace matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.
(?:\{(?!\d)\s*|(?<!\d)\} *| *\n *(?= ))


Demo

The expression can be broken down as follows.
(?:          : begin a non-capture group
  \{         : match '{'
  (?!\d)     : negative lookahead asserts that the following character 
               is not a digit
  \s*        : match zero or more whitespaces
|            : or
  (?<!\d)    : negative lookbehind asserts the previous character
               is not a digit
  \}         : match '}'
  \ *        : match zero or more spaces
|            : or
  \ *\n\ *   : match zero or more spaces followed by a newline followed
               by zero or more spaces
  (?=\ )     : positive lookahead asserts the next character is a space
)            : end non-capture group

Note that I have escaped space characters to make them visible.

FYI GNU grep with -P supports lookarounds and the ability to output hacked strings. I wouldn't recommend using it (if you have grep -P then you almost certainly have perl so just use perl), but it exists.

One way to do this could be using multiple steps, which makes it much easier (to read and to write regex).
Here is an implementation in Python:
import re

A = """
VARA {APPLE}
VARB {
          ORANGE
          BANANA
     }
VARC {
          KIWI{0}
          KIWI{1}
          BERRY
     }
VARD {CHERRY{0} MELON}
"""

A = re.sub(r'(?m)^(\S+)\s+{([^\r\n]+)}$', r'\1 \2', A)
A = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', A)
A = re.sub(r'{\s+', '', A)
A = re.sub(r'\s+}', '', A)
print(A)


Prints

VARA APPLE
VARB ORANGE BANANA
VARC KIWI{0} KIWI{1} BERRY
VARD CHERRY{0} MELON



(?m)^(\S+)\s+{([^\r\n]+)}$ removes the inline {}.
\s{2,} removes all multiline extra spaces.
{\s+ and \s+} removes the remaining multiline {}.


If, like in your sample input, braces can nest only two levels deep and inner braces can enclose only digits, you can use grep -oPz with a pattern that matches just the characters needed to assemble into your desired output after filtering the null bytes produced by the -z option with col:
grep -oPz '\w+ |(?:{\s*\K| )\w+(?:{\d+})?|(?<=(?<!\d)})\n' input.txt | col


You can use this sed chain:
cat myfile.txt | sed -E 's/ \{|([A-Z])\}$| \}/\1 /g' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -E 's/ *$/\n/' | sed -E 's/ +/ /g' | sed 's/ VAR/\nVAR/g'

It's a little clumsy, tackling each part of the problem separately, but works.

Probably avoid the useless use of cat; the repeated sed invocations can probably also be refactored into a single script, and most modern sed variants allow you to do s/\n/ / or similar to get rid of the tr (also sed has a built-in command y which duplicates tr).

Any time you do tr '\n' <anything> you're creating output that's no longer a valid POSIX text file and so entering undefined behavior territory and so YMMV with whatever any subsequent text processing tool does with that as input.

Try:
\s{2,}|\{(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\}$

replace by a single space   (see regex101).
As you will see you then have a surplus on spaces between "VARX" and the first item, but you can handle them by matching \b\h+\b
and replacing with a single space   (see regex101). Further spaces at the end of lines can be removed by \s+$ replacing with empty string (see regex101)

Explanation
The stragegy is to remove unwanted parts; keeping only what you want. Unwanted is defined as:

\s{2,}: any time there are two or more spaces (including line breaks)
|: or
\{(?!\d): an opening bracket that does not have a digit right afterwards
|: or
(?<!\d)\}$: a closing bracket at the end of a line that does not have a digit right in front


You're trying to do two things: remove outermost matching braces and collapse spaces.
To find matching braces with balanced sets of left braces and right braces , you can use a recursive PCRE pattern supported by grep with the -P option. Use the -o option to output only the matching strings, and use the -z option to output matches as null-separated records.
You can then use awk to collapse spaces and strip the first and last braces of each null-separated record from the output:
grep -oPz '\w+\s*\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}' input.txt | \
awk '-F[[:space:]]+' '-vOFS= ' '-vRS=}\0' '{sub(/{/,"");$1=$1}1'


You should mention that requires both GNU grep for -P and GNU awk for multi-char RS and allowing \0 in RS.

There will be no way to do this using grep, since there are also curly brackets you do not want to get rid of, and you cannot distinguish them using regex only.

Although you're correct about grep, this answer in and of itself isn't that helpful to OP. It would've been nice to add some pointers about an alternative solution, like the other answers have done.

I will do that next time, thanks

You know you can [edit] this answer, right?

Using any POSIX awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        tmp = rec = rec " " $0
        while ( gsub(/\{[^{}]*}/, "", tmp) );
    }
    tmp !~ /[{}]/ {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ", rec)
        gsub(/^ | ?}? ?$/, "", rec)
        sub(/ ?\{ ?/, " ", rec)
        print rec
        rec = ""
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
VARA APPLE
VARB ORANGE BANANA
VARC KIWI{0} KIWI{1} BERRY
VARD CHERRY{0} MELON

That removes all matching pairs of {...} from a temp copy of the input record read so far until there are none left and that's when it knows it has a complete record to print, after removing extraneous white space and the first { and last }.
Alternatively, instead of trying to match up braces, you could just print the previous record every time a line starts with an alphabetic character, as in VARB, and at the end of the input, e.g.:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    /^[[:alpha:]]/ { prt() }
    { rec = rec " " $0 }
    END { prt() }

    function prt() {
        if ( rec ) {
            gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, " ", rec)
            gsub(/^ | ?}? ?$/, "", rec)
            sub(/ ?\{ ?/, " ", rec)
            print rec
            rec = ""
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh file
VARA APPLE
VARB ORANGE BANANA
VARC KIWI{0} KIWI{1} BERRY
VARD CHERRY{0} MELON


It's doable without using capturing groups or look-aheads/look-behinds … it's just a bit hideous that's all - it comes down to using sentinels and dummy seps to emulate the effect of grep -o.
The full input file is processed all in a single shot.
 echo '
VARA {APPLE}
VARB {
          ORANGE
          BANANA
     }
VARC {
          KIWI{0}
          KIWI{1}
          BERRY
     }
VARD {CHERRY{0} MELON}' |


mawk 'END { gsub(/[^0-9][}][^\n]*\n+/, "&\6") 

            gsub(/[{][0-9]+[}]/, "\5&\3") * (NF = NF) &&
                gsub(/\5 +/, "{") < gsub(/ +\3/, "}")
 
           print $+(gsub(/\n+/, _) + gsub(/\6/, 
                           "\n") < -gsub(/[ \t]+/, OFS)) 

 } BEGIN { RS = "^$" (ORS = _ = (_)_)
           FS = "[[:space:]]*][{}][[:space:]]*]" } '


VARA APPLE 
VARB ORANGE BANANA 
VARC KIWI{0} KIWI{1} BERRY 
VARD CHERRY{0} MELON 

The code showcases how BEGIN { } and END { } patterns don't even need to be in sequential order for awk to process it.
